# How do I handle a header animation(textview and an image moves to the centre) when an android user scrolls down?

Tags: android

Basically, I want to shrink and then move a  header and a small image to the centre when the user scrolls down. And it should be a smooth progressive animation based on how far the user is scrolled down.

Is there a way to do this without using a AppBar / toolbar tags?

Answer (score 0):

I can give a hint as what you want is a completely custom movement tracker. You can use Scroll Offset as your main value to change any other component in your activity or fragment. for Recyclerview for example:

```js
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    // this is where you use scroll offset to animate something
    someView.animate().translationY(recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()).setDuration(0).start();
  }
});
```

This is just a hint

For animating Height & View Positions you would need Value Animators & Object Animators as well